# How and when to use ActorIdentity in Akka

Tags: akka

Can anyone explain how and when to use `ActorIdentity` with a good example?

From documents I can find that "There is a built-in Identify message that all Actors will understand and automatically reply to with a ActorIdentity message containing the ActorRef".

Does that statement mean obtained actor say `actorSelector` have ActorIdentity message  wrapped in my actor?

```
ActorSelection actorSelector =  getContext().actorSelection("/A/B/*");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you send an `Identify` message to an `ActorSelection` the actor will respond, if it exists, with an `ActorIdentity` message.

If the actor exists the `ActorIdentity` message will contain a `Some(actorRef)`.   It is more efficient to send messages to `ActorRef`s than `ActorSelection`s.

For example (from the manual):

```
class Follower extends Actor {
  val identifyId = 1
  context.actorSelection("/user/another") ! Identify(identifyId)

  def receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, Some(ref)) =>
      context.watch(ref)
      context.become(active(ref))
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, None) => context.stop(self)

  }

  def active(another: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case Terminated(`another`) => context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

The section in the manual that covers this is called [Identifying Actors via Actor Selection](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection).